# how to increase area of input file element?

Tags: css, html

I am using some style to increase the area of input file element. In order to ease dropping file to this element i would like to increase its area. Using the css property width and height increases the area but is there a way to align the choose file to the middle or center.

```
<div id="container">

<input type=file style="border: 1px solid black; width: 400px; height: 400px;">

</div>
```

[image]

Is it possible to achieve something like this using just css and html? I appreciate any help!

[image]

Comment: For drag n drop functionality you have to include javascript code.

Comment: @Usman in internet explorer dropping doesnt set the file input value. in chrome dropping works. so i wonder if javascript is the right way to do this.

Comment: I think javascript is the only option for drag and drop functionality. You can also use javascript based drag and drop library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS to make the Drag&Drop section the size of the whole container:

```css
.file {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.file-input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%  
}
```

```html
<div class="file">
  <input class="file-input" type="file">
</div>
```

But in order to center the "Preview" and have all the area to Drag&Drop you must use Js, here is a CodePen that you could you as a base: https://codepen.io/prasanjit/pen/NxjZMO.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some padding:

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type=file>
</div>
```

Comment: in internet explorer dropping doesnt set the file input value. in chrome dropping works. so i wonder if javascript is the right way to do this.

Comment: this is a simple method to achieve what you want, of course with some potential drawbacks. But yes, the proper way to do this is via Javascript.

Comment: there's a nice guide here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop

Comment: dropping the file is opening the file in chrome. why is not preventdefault not working?

Comment: have you added the dragover ev listener? ondragover="dragOverHandler(event);